# VS2010 custom installer with own forms

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

I am currently using custom forms in my VS2010 generated installer. Here is the code

```
namespace MyWinFormApp
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class MyInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {
        public MyInstaller()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver) 
        { 
            base.Install(stateSaver); 
        }

        public override void Commit(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.Commit(savedState);

            InstallForm topmostForm = new InstallForm();  

            topmostForm.BringToFront(); 
            topmostForm.TopMost = true; 
            topmostForm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

This shows my InstallForm as a popup while my installer generated wizard is still hanging in the background. The problem here is that even though I tried to make it modal. It still allows actions to be performed on the installer generated wizard while installing on my Windows 7 pc. It is not truly modal.

Any way to make my InstallForm as modal or get it to show as one of the installer generated wizard windows and not separately as a popup?

Using another install creator is not an option. I need to use Visual Studio only.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know to make the form modal is to make the installer generated wizard window owner of your form. But it is not a trivial task. Another complication is that your form and installer generated wizard run in different processes.

One way to overcome it is to hide installer wizard window. Although I'm not sure there's an easy way to do it. Otherwise you'll face the same problem as above: you have to find the *correct* installer window.

**The better approach** would be not to use forms shown from custom actions. You can create *native* MSI forms and insert them into the wizard UI sequence. And form would need to be topmost; I'd not recommend using topmost windows in an installer.